# pushing 8 chars string on stack in x64 assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm, shellcode

I am working on a very basic 64 bits intel program.

I want to push some chars on stack.

It works fine if i do like this:

```
mov rcx, 'messsage.'
push rcx
```

This is good because my string message is 8 bytes length (64 bits). It perfectly fits in rcx register.

Now, it does not work if i do this:

```
push 'message.'
```

or

```
push qword 'message'.
```

I do not understand why this is not possible.
Because it is possible to push immediate values like this:

```
push 0xFFAA0000FFAA0000
```

I just want to understand.

Thanks

Comment: No, `push 0xFFAA0000FFAA0000` is not encodeable.  Only `push imm32` sign-extended to 64 bits.

Comment: You can do `mov rax, qword 'message.'` and then `push rax`.